# 2 Conditions for the same column in a SQl query

Tags: sql, sql-server

How can i get the distinct dates in a table where R.TypeofDayID = 2 and it should not include dates with R.TypeofDayID = 1

I can get all the distinct dates for R.TypeofDayID = 2 using the below query but i am not sure how i can add a condition to get dates where TypeofDayID = 2 and the date should not have TypeofDayID = 1 in any row.

```
Select count(distinct(R.Date)) from RepInfo R   
where R.TypeofDayID = 2 and Month(R.Date) = 2 and Year(R.Date) = 2013
```

I hope i am clear. This is in SQL Server 2005. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Select R.Date, count(*) as cnt
from RepInfo R   
where Month(R.Date) = 2 and Year(R.Date) = 2013
group by R.Date
having sum(case when TypeofDayID <> 2 then 1 else 0 end) = 0
```

Comment: I think the having clause should have the condition `TypeofDayID = 1`.

Comment: Hmm. But if I add that I need to specify a `where` clause with `TypeofDayID = 2` and then it won't work.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using a COUNT() function in your select statement if you want the the output to be a list of distinct dates?  Would you get your desired result from changing your select to something like this:

Select distinct(R.Date)

Comment: I actually need the count of distinct dates! Thank you.